# Android, DragListener combined with Single Tap or OnClick/OnTouch

Tags: android, drag

I'm struggling at combining DragListener with SingeTap action in an imageView. They work fine separately but how this two should be combined?

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            Log.e("SINGLE TAP","?");
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("TRYING", "");
                            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                            v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                            break;
                        default: break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Still doesn't seem to work. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ACTION_UP` will be called after a drag event finishes, as well as after a tap event finishes. Therefore you should have a flag that detects if a drag event occurred or not. Here is an example

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            private boolean isDrag = false;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!isDrag) {
                            // action was a single tap
                        }
                        isDrag = false; // reset the flag
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        isDrag = true; // set the flag
                        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("TRYING", "");
                        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                        break;
                    default: break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well, much appreciated !

Comment: Be careful when assuming that any ACTION_MOVE event is a drag. Often when tapping, that action is also triggered due to small natural movements.